# Cannot run uvicorn command on windows despite installing it and adding in path variables

Tags: python, windows, fastapi, windows-terminal, uvicorn

As the title, I have installed uvicorn using the powershell, and added the environment variable. But whenever I run the command, I get the same error. I know I must be doing something small and stupid, but following every answer on SO tells me the same thing, and I have no leads at all.

[image: env variable]
[image: error screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but to anyone still looking for a solution if you're on windows at least.

- Do pip install **uvicorn**, then do pip uninstall **uvicorn**, this
  will give you the directory location of where **uvicorn** is
  installed.
- Type n to not uninstall, you are just getting the path. Go to the
  location in your explorer where it was installed, for me, it was in
  `users/AppData/roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages`.
- Copy the `"uvicorn"` and `"uvicorn-X.XX.Xdist-info"` folders, then go
  to `users/AppData/roaming/Python/Python37/Scripts` and copy the
  "uvicorn.exe".
- You are going to paste all three of these items to something like
  path: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts"`.
- After this, go back to your terminal and try `"uvicorn main:app --reload"`.

And it should work now.

Comment: pip has a command to dump information about a package that could be used here instead of uninstall `pip show <package_name>`

Answer (score 8):

Try do the following

```
python3 -m uvicorn main:app
```

Answer (score 0):

Me I've just copied folders:

- "uvicorn" and "uvicorn-X.XX.Xdist-info" from *C:\Users\samue\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages*
- and the file "uvicorn.exe" from *C:\Users\samue\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts*

to my default python folder:
*C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts*, and I added the link to the .exe file to the environment variables path. It worked!

Answer (score -1):

Usually console won't take the changes when applied to environmental variables when it is open. So can you try once closing the powershell or CMD and reopen.

Comment: I did restart the powershell everytime I did the changes...